# Run a Task Scheduler Batch File that sends out an email before Server 2016 Shutdown

Tags: shutdown, windows-server, taskscheduler

I have a cmd file that sends out an email (email program -> stunnel -> gmail).

I have a Task Scheduler task that triggers when the computer (Windows 2016) starts - *No problems here*.

I would like to setup a Task Scheduler action that does the same thing when the computer is shutting down. The batch file takes about 10 - 20 seconds to execute and needs to be able to access the internet in order to send out the email.

I am aware that one can tie an event in Task Scheduler to the Event Viewer but do not know the event I should latch on to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to generate the email by triggering on any one of these event IDs 1074, 6006, 6008.